# On Android, which is better to define the interface, using an XML or code?

Tags: android, android-layout, interface

In my first project i used XML for Interface. Now i'm going to start new project, it's big enough: fixed footer, header and content with pictures, map and so on. 
Question: for my new project which one is better to build Interface: using XML with external scripts, or drop the XML and create everything from the code?

Comment: Well sometimes it can be smart to make some part of the layout in code, but the big chunks should be made in xml, anything else really is trying to swim against the stream and isn't recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that is more or less a preferences question. If you prefer using XML stick to it, as it provides the necessary features for almost anything regarding layout.

If you have some parts of your app where you need to make a programmatically layout, you can do that in the specific case.

My experience is that once you get the hang of XML layout it is easy and flexible, whereas code layouts are more difficult to manage.

Answer (score 1):

XML layouts provide you with a lot of flexibility that is harder to achieve through code.

- You can merge and include layouts. (http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html and http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html).
- You can create layouts for different localizations and configurations.
- You can easier reuse layouts in other activities, fragments and projects. For example, Android ships with various layouts that you can reuse, like android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 (layout for a simple text row).
- Use stubs (http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-stubs.html).

Notice that you can use layouts anywhere through the layout inflater. Sometimes it is necessary to write code to create views, but I try to avoid that as much as possible. To avoid XML layouts for a whole project sounds like masochism to me due to all the boring code you need to write to create layout params etc. I think you will quickly understand why Android got layout XML and appreciate this feature if you go ahead with a code-only project for something bigger than "Hello World".